RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /login/: User has no profile
I'm new to Django and web development in general. I'm building an E-commerce store with a functioning user registration and login system. When I try to log in, I get a User has no profile error. I'm honestly stuck and don't know how to fix this. I believe the problem has to do with my models.py files in my store app and user app. Any help is appreciated.
store.models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True, related_name = 'customer') 
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 200, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

user.models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self): # returns a ready friendly string representation of class object
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile' # prints out "username" Profile
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

user.views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST) # contains username and 2 passwords that user enter
        
        if form.is_valid(): # checks if data is valid, if valid, this conditional statement will create an account
            user = form.save() # saves user info database
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username') 
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in') # displays message if form data is valid
            return redirect('login') 
    else: 
        form = UserRegisterForm()

    return render(request, 'user/register.html', {'form' : form})

I tried to change the 'related_name' for both my Customer and Profile models. If I change the related_name to profile, then I would get an error that says User has no customer attribute or something like that.
